# strtotime on incorrect dates

Tags: php, strtotime

I found something odd about strtotime().

On dates that do not exist it returns the day after.

```
$d30= strtotime("2017-06-30");
Echo $d30 ."\n";
Echo date("Y-m-d", $d30)."\n\n";  // 2017-06-30

$d31= strtotime("2017-06-31");
Echo $d31 ."\n";
Echo date("Y-m-d", $d31)."\n\n";  // 2017-07-01

$d32= strtotime("2017-06-32");
Echo $d32 ."\n";
Echo date("Y-m-d", $d32);         // 1970-01-01
```

https://3v4l.org/AjMAE

I understand the last one. It returns nothing as it's an error.
But why does the second one return first of July?
Is it a meant to be functional, in case you make a mistake it will "correct you"? Or is it a true bug in strtotime()?

Comment: Month 'JUNE' have only 30 days . so if you write 31 PHP date function automatically convert it to next date.

Comment: So it's a meant to be function? I can't find anything in the manual about it.

Comment: Value 31 is an acceptable value for strtotime, 32 is not

Comment: Why does it do it that way?  Because that's how they chose to implement the fixup.  If you read the entry on php.net this is a very loose function.  See also how they handle Jan 30  and 31 with "+1 month"

Comment: @DaveS Not sure I found the correct one you mention. Can you link to it? Name of the poster is a link

Comment: Use checkdate() function for date is valid or not after call strtotime function

Comment: The comment I was thinking of was for +1 month, similar fixup - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#111989

Comment: @DaveS Thanks, that was the same one I read then.

Comment: @HussyBorad Thanks for checkdata()! I didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [strtotime()](http://PHP.net/strtotime) you will see the first parameter is:

> **time**
>   A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

If you follow the link for the date and time formats and go to [*Date Formats*](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) you will see:

[image]

Thus for the date format (I.e. *DD*), 01-31 is valid    (since a *3* can only be followed by a *0* or *1*) despite the month. Depending on the supplied month and date value the date will be adjusted.

Also found in the notes on that same page:

> **Note**:
>   It is possible to over- and underflow the *dd* and *DD* format. Day 0 means the last day of previous month, whereas overflows count into the next month. This makes "2008-08-00" equivalent to "2008-07-31" and "2008-06-31" equivalent to "2008-07-01" (June only has 30 days).<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)</sup>

Hence *06-31* is valid while *06-32* is invalid.

Additionally, in the [User Contributed Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php#usernotes) section, the [note by Mirek at 2015-04-01 01:14](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php#117014) might be useful/interesting:

> Note: the day (dd or DD) is first checked for range 0..31 and only if it fits, the overflow and underflow mechanism may apply. If not, strtotime() simply returns false.
>   If you need unlimited over/underflow for date calculations (for example 2015-01-40 to 2015-02-09), use [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) instead.<sup>[2](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php#Hcom117014)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php#Hcom117014</sub>

Comment: Ha! I never clicked on the link about valid dates. Didn't think there was anything to read there. I expected there to be enough information on the main page to figure it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As day `31` of a month is possible `strtotime()` will correct the date for you. If you try it with February (2017-02-31) it will correct to `2017-03-03`. This is what you found.

So, what it essentially does is:

1. get the date
2. check if the date is in a valid range (days per
   month)
3. if not valid count days into the next month

This behaviour is implemented into the `strtotime` function itself.

There was a great comment on the documentation page about this, but I am no longer able to find it. This [comment](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#107331) provides some extra information (be sure to check the link in the comment).

Comment: Thanks! Odd that there is so little information about this in the manual itself. You have to read the comments about the "+1 month" and such to find it.

Comment: Indeed, @SamOnela has a citation (from the documentation about dates) that explains it.