# PHP date, how to prevent php date for auto convert to next day?

Tags: php

As you may know, php date will return a valid date on these dates:

```
year-04-31

year-06-31

year-09-31
```

I have read other [SO thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362850/strtotime-on-incorrect-dates) about the non existed date, but this thread did not solve my problem. My goal is to prevent php to automatically let these date convert to next day. For example, if user input date `2018-04-31`, the system will prompt an error.

```
$value = '2018-06-31'; // assume user input this date
if(date is 04-31, 06-31 or 09-31) // i have no idea what to put here
  echo 'wrong date, please enter again';
```

**EDIT**

someone actually posted this question as duplicate for [for this thread in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format)...which part it says something about 4-31, 6-31, 9-31? please dont simply mark this as duplicate, make your comparison between my question and the others before mark. thank you

Comment: You can use input type 'date' for avoid this problem.

Comment: please read my edits

Comment: Why does the duplicate have to hyper specifically address 4-31, 6-31 and 9-31? Your question can and should be generalised to *How to check whether a given date actually exists?*, for which the duplicate is perfect. Specifically I'd highlight https://stackoverflow.com/a/29093651/476.

Comment: I prefer this `if((new DateTime($date))->format('Y-m-d') != $date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
<?php

$date = '2018-06-31';


function checkIsAValidDate($date){
    return (bool)strtotime($date) && date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) == $date;
}

if(checkIsAValidDate($date) == 1){
    echo 'valid';   
}else{
    echo 'not valid';
}

?>
```

This will validate the format, and that the date is real. IE, there are only 30 days in the month of June.

Comment: this is more simpler with great explanation...thank you

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will return `FALSE` in case it cannot convert string to timestamp. So you can try:

```
if (strtotime('<your date time string here>') === false) {
   // TODO.
}
```

----- EDIT -----
Thanks to @Nick.

`strtotime` may wrong in some case as '02-30'. So I suggest [another solution](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php):

```
$date = explode('-', '<date time string>');
if (checkdate($date[1], $date[2], $date[0]) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: `strtotime('2018-02-30')` does not return false, it returns a timestamp equivalent to `2018-03-02`

Comment: i tried your code here `https://rextester.com/PBKYQ2169` does not work

Comment: so your solution is to manually check the months and day of a dates? is there a better solution?

Answer (score -2):

I guess you don't to allow users to input 31st when the month is of 30 days. In that case why don't you simple use a datepicker? Instead of allowing users to enter the date make them choose one. If you are scared about editing after the date is chosen then use a javascript function to disable text input in the filed and allow only clicks which makes datepicker to appear.

Comment: The server always has to do input validation. There's no client-side way to enforce valid values.